# Visual Studio Code not recognizing java project

Tags: java, gradle, visual-studio-code

VS Code is not recognizing my java project.  The project is template code for a minecraft mod found [here](https://github.com/FabricMC/fabric-example-mod/).  Ive installed the plugins

- "Debugger for Java"
- "Java Extension Pack"
- "Language Support for Java by Redhat"
- "Java Test Runner"
- "Project Manager for Java"

I also get an error related to gradle.

```
Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip'.
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00
invalid type code: 00
```

And here is my settings.json file

```json
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/.classpath": true,
        "**/.project": true,
        "**/.settings": true,
        "**/.factorypath": true
    },
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "java.configuration.updateBuildConfiguration": "interactive",
    "java.home": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-16-openjdk-amd64",
    "java.configuration.runtimes": [
        {
          "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
          "path": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64",
          "default": true
        },
    ]
}
```

I have no code completion for my Java files.  Before it was working and in the lower right corner of visual studio it displayed the java version i was using but now it just says Java.  I'm assuming its because there is a problem with gradle and thus cannot figure out my java version.  Thank you for your time.

**Update:**
This seems to work and give me auto completion but i stil get a gradle related error mention above.

```json
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/.classpath": true,
        "**/.project": true,
        "**/.settings": true,
        "**/.factorypath": true
    },
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "java.configuration.updateBuildConfiguration": "interactive",
    "java.home": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-16-openjdk-amd64",
    "java.configuration.runtimes": [
        {
          "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
          "path": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64",
          "default": true
        },
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-16",
            "path": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-16-openjdk-amd64",
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: New update on vs code asks for running/compiling the project files if you trust it. You may choose not to trust the project, so it can't run/compile the files automatically https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspace-trust

Comment: Yes,  I received a pop up and checked, Yes, I trust the authors, but i still get the gradle error and vscode is unable to find my java project.

Comment: It does prompt me with, "The workspace contains Java projects. Would you like to import them?", but seems to fail to import them.

Comment: @LeadVaxeral what version of Java and what version of gradle are you using?

Comment: Sounds like a mismatch in versions

Comment: https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/1594

Comment: @Zack I have multiple versions of java installed.  But my default java version specified in my settings folder is 1.8.  gradle --version gives me "Gradle 7.0.2" and this for my java -version "openjdk version "1.8.0_292""

Answer (score 14):

Run `Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace` on command palette

- In my case, I have no settings files like `.project`, `./settings/...files`

Comment: Why does this work - does VS Code (Java extension) need the mentioned settings files?

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me, but without modifying the settings.json file

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is stuck with the same problem as me make sure your settings.json file looks similar to mine including both java 1.8 run config and the java 11+ run config same as the one specified as the home path.  That should fix the java language level.  The gradle error you can ignore but you must use gradle runClient instead of the run configuration that vscode provides.  Happy modding :D

Comment: Java extension needs **JDK11 or recent version** to support so if you set jdk1.8 as `java.home`, the extension won't work well.

Comment: But i never said to do that though i said to set a run config for java 11+ with the same path as the home path @MollyWang  Just as i have it in the second json file i posted.

Comment: But i guess the clarification is fine.  Thank you @MollyWang.

Comment: What da hellll man.

Comment: Sorry im a bit crude.  I didnt mean to come off that way.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved the problem by creating a new Java Project, and comparing the files that were generated.
In particular I found missing entries in `.project`

```xml
<buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>          <!-- was missing -->
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature> <!-- was missing -->
        <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
    </natures>
```

also some settings in `.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` were missing but they did not immediately fixed the problem until I added the above.

Of course, you need to clean the workspace everytime you make a change (with the `... -> clean workspace` or the command palette `Java > clean Java Language server workspace`

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the methods mentioned above, but unfortunately, none of them worked. I have an existing Java project and I've installed the "Extension Pack for Java", but VSCode still couldn't recognize this Java project.

Eventually, I found a solution. I closed the current Java project, opened a new VSCode window, and directly opened the folder of the Java project. After doing this, everything went back to normal!

If you're facing a similar issue, you might want to give this method a try.